# What's the equivalent of setCopyrightAlignment in HERE map JavaScript API 3.0?

Tags: here-api

Does anyone know how to change the position of the HERE map copyright text in version 3.0 of the JavaScript API?  I've found a method in version 2.5 called setCopyrightAlignment to do that, but the closest I can find in 3.0 is the ICopyright interface that only lets me change the text.  I need to put the copyright text in another corner.  Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get to the imprint element and style via:

```
var imprintElement = map.getImprint().getElement();
var imprintStyle = map.getImprint().getStyle();
```

From there on you can do whatever you need by applying CSS styles.

The imprint is positioned absolutely, so top, bottom, left and right are the properties you will probably want to modify.